# Procedurally splitting and merging paths

Tags: game-design, procedural-generation

I'm making a text-based adventure which sends the player along different paths depending on their choices.  Each scene is like a node in a directed graph. Each node has a time step which is equal to the number of nodes prior + 1.  There is a maximum of Tn nodes per time step, say 5, and so you can visualise this in this way:

[image: Paths.png]

I want to generate paths like these.

Where a node points to more than one other, that could be called a fork and where two point to one, that could be called a merge.

At any particular timestep there will tend to be Tn / 2 paths, only rarely going down to one or up to Tn.

Does anyone have ideas or know of any similar work?

(One small issue - paths never cross - that is, those on the left stay on the left until merging to the right.  And there's no wrapping from far left to far right.  Because of this, it seems like nodes on the far left or far right of a timestep will have a smaller probability of merging.  Is this avoidable?)

Comment: The probability of the second-from-the-left thread merging is equal to the probability of its left neighbour merging right (AKA merging at all) plus the probability of its right neighbour merging left. So if this node has any chance of merging right, then its total chance of merging is greater than that for the leftmost node. The only way to completely avoid this uneven probability is if the threads are grouped in pairs, so odd threads only merge right and even threads only merge left (and merges/splits only occur in twos) which sounds like it's probably more restrictive than you want.

Comment: It sounds like I'll just have to live with that small problem then.  I made it seem like the left-right thing is the issue when really I just want to find previous work, or ideas on how to tackle the whole algorithm.  For example deciding how to process the merges and forks.  Google is turning up nothing.

Comment: Do you want the whole branching structure generated at the start, or as players progress?  If you're generating the paths as the game is going, you can branch left/right regardless and just pretend it was there the whole time

Comment: That's an interesting point - unfortunately I'm going to have some of the gameplay based on whether the player is taking the 'fastest' path - depending on what obstacles exist in each node.  So the whole thing has to be generated at the beginning.

I've worked out a few things and could add them as a final 'answer' of sorts.  However, since the question doesn't fit the standard Q/A format maybe I should delete it.

Comment: This looks like the plot of a make your own adventure book. Is the intent for the nodes to represent plot? (Or location/game-state ect.) Are you trying to make this structure yourself and then turn it into game-code, or is the game supposed to proceduraly generate something like this? You mention that you want to track whether or not the player is taking the fastest path. If that is the primary purpose, you could re phrase the question in terms of the problem (this may or may not change it enough to merit a different question post).

Comment: Yes that was the intention - I loved the Fighting Fantasy series.  The game "engine" will choose randomly from a list of pre-written texts, putting one at each node.  I'm not sure how important it is to rephrase the question to be honest - all the key things are mentioned.  The tracking of the player is only auxiliary.

Comment: To answer your question they will represent location more than anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base requirements:

- Input n, totalTime
- Max n nodes at time T
- Minimum 1 node at time T
- Average n/2 nodes at time T
- T is an int in the range of [0, totalTime)

There are three different options for each node at each time step

- Continue
- Split
- Merge

For each time T, every node should have a chance to do one of the options, with different weights depending on how full the tree structure is

- Having 1 node should reduce merge chance to 0
- Having n nodes should reduce split chance to 0
- To keep it around n/2 nodes, a somewhat normal distribution should be used

---

It may be useful to put all related scene data together

```
class Scene
{
    Scene[] nextScenes; //a list of the next scenes in the graph
    //your other data here, setting/plot/things
}
```

Creation steps:

1. Initialize root of tree to build from
2. Iterate until the tree is depth totalTime

   - Each node picks if it wants to attempt to grow or shrink the tree
   - The next layer is built based on the last layers actions to grow/shrink
3. Return the built tree

This will be the only method that needs to be called by the game to request/build a tree

```
Scene generateTree(int n, int totalTime)
{
    //initialize the root
    Scene root = new Scene();

    //iterate until tree is deep enough
    Scene[] lastLayer = {root}; //helper data structure
    for(int i = 1; i < totalTime; i++)
    {
        int[] actions = new int[lastLayer.length];
        int nextSize = getActions(actions, n);
        lastLayer = addLayer(lastLayer, actions, nextSize);
    }

    //return the tree
    return root;
}
```

Node grow/shrink choice logic:

1. Each node picks a desired layer size
2. Grow if the next layer is estimated to be too small
3. Shrink if the next layer is too big
4. Otherwise maintain size

This can be put into a function that takes the current estimate for the next layer's size, and the max nodes possible

```
Random rand = new Random();
int getAction(int nextSize, int n) //action of a single node, < 0 shrink, > 0 grow
{
    return rand.nextInt(n) + 1 - nextSize; //[0, n) + 1 - (0, n]
    //can get a bit fancier if you want more nodes to continue instead of grow/shrink
    //int range = 1; //total bonus chances at choosing continue (could use n * 0.1)
    //int r = rand.nextInt(n + range) + 1;
    //return (r < nextSize ? -1 : (r > nextSize + range ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Choosing actions of the nodes:

- If the selected node already is marked as merging left/right, it can't shrink further, but can grow with a split
- To shrink, a node must have an adjacent node to merge into (node must be continue or split)

  - When merging, the node being merged into should be marked as well
- Nodes default to continue

The code for choosing merging actions gets a bit lengthy from all of the different conditions

```
private static final int CONTINUE = 0;
private static final int SPLIT = 1;
private static final int MERGEL = 2;
private static final int MERGER = 3;
int getActions(int[] actions, int n)
{
    int nextSize = actions.length; //estimated next layer size
    boolean[] processed = new boolean[actions.length];

    for(int i = actions.length; i > 0; i--) //loop through each node of the last layer
    {
        int selection = rand.nextInt(i); //randomly choose from [0, i) to process, first loop iteration can select any index, last iteration can only select the 1 remaining unprocessed node
        for(int j = 0; j < actions.length; j++) //figure out the actual index selected (skip processed nodes)
            if(!processed[j] && selection-- == 0)
            {
                selection = j; //set selection to the actual index
                processed[j] = true; //mark selection as being processed
                break;
            }

        //process the selected node
        int choice = getAction(nextSize, n); //goal size for this node to work toward (will average to n/2)
        boolean grow = choice > 0;
        boolean shrink = choice < 0;
        if(selection == 0) //on the left edge
            if(actions[selection] == CONTINUE) //doesn't have an action
            {
                if(grow)
                {
                    actions[selection] = SPLIT;
                    nextSize++;
                }
                else
                    if(shrink && actions[selection + 1] != MERGER)
                    {
                        actions[selection] = MERGER;
                        if(actions[selection + 1] == CONTINUE) //mark it as merging a direction
                            actions[selection + 1] = MERGEL;
                        nextSize--;
                    }
            }
            else //has an action already (MERGER)
                if(grow)
                {
                    actions[selection] = SPLIT;
                    nextSize--;
                }
        else
            if(selection == lastLayerCount - 1) //on the right edge
            {
                if(actions[selection] == CONTINUE) //doesn't have an action
                {
                    if(grow)
                    {
                        actions[selection] = SPLIT;
                        nextSize++;
                    }
                    else
                        if(shrink && actions[selection - 1] != MERGEL)
                        {
                            actions[selection] = MERGEL;
                            if(actions[selection - 1] == CONTINUE) //mark it as merging a direction
                                actions[selection - 1] = MERGER;
                            nextSize--;
                        }
                }
                else //has an action already (MERGEL)
                    if(grow)
                    {
                        actions[selection] = SPLIT;
                        nextSize++;
                    }
            }
            else //in the middle, has two neighbors
            {
                if(actions[selection] == CONTINUE) //doesn't have an action
                {
                    if(grow)
                    {
                        actions[selection] = SPLIT;
                        nextSize++;
                    }
                    else
                        if(shrink)
                            if(actions[selection - 1] != MERGEL)
                                if(actions[selection + 1] != MERGER) //can go left or right
                                {
                                    if(rand.nextBoolean()) //merge left
                                    {
                                        actions[selection] = MERGEL;
                                        if(actions[selection - 1] == CONTINUE)
                                            actions[selection - 1] = MERGER;
                                    }
                                    else //merge right
                                    {
                                        actions[selection] = MERGER;
                                        if(actions[selection + 1] == CONTINUE)
                                            actions[selection + 1] = MERGEL;
                                    }
                                    nextSize--;
                                }
                                else //can only go left
                                {
                                    actions[selection] = MERGEL;
                                    if(actions[selection - 1] == CONTINUE)
                                        actions[selection - 1] = MERGER;
                                    nextSize--;
                                }
                            else
                                if(action[selection + 1] != MERGER) //can only go right
                                {
                                    actions[selection] = MERGER;
                                    if(actions[selection + 1] == CONTINUE)
                                        actions[selection + 1] = MERGEL;
                                    nextSize--;
                                }
                }
            }
    }

    return nextSize;
}
```

Merging the actions of the nodes:

- Variables `i` and `index` show the position in `lastLayer` and `nextLayer` respectively
- `CONTINUE` connects `lastLayer[i]` to `nextLayer[index]`, incrementing `i` and `index`
- `SPLIT` connects `lastLayer[i]` to `nextLayer[index]` and `nextLayer[index+1]`, incrementing `i` by 1 and `index` by 2
- `MERGEL` connects `lastLayer[i]` to `nextLayer[index-1]`, only incrementing `i`
- `MERGER` connects `lastLayer[i]` to `nextLayer[index]`, only incrementing `i`

  - If `MERGEL` comes right after, it processes that action too

    - `lastLayer[i+1]` is connected to `nextLayer[index]`, incrementing `i` and `index`

The last step is putting the actions together and adding a layer

```
Scene[] addLayer(Scene[] lastLayer, int[] actions, int nextSize)
{
    Scene[] nextLayer = new Scene[nextSize];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < lastLayer.length; i++)
        switch(actions[i])
        {
            case CONTINUE:
                lastLayer[i].nextScenes = {nextLayer[index++]};
                break;
            case SPLIT:
                lastLayer[i].nextScenes = {nextLayer[index++], nextLayer[index++]};
                break;
            case MERGER:
                lastLayer[i].nextScenes = {nextLayer[index]};
                if(actions[i + 1] == MERGEL) //handle the next too
                    lastLayer[++i].nextScenes = {nextLayer[index++]};
                break;
            case MERGEL:
                actions[i] = {nextLayer[index - 1]};
                break;
        }

    return nextLayer;
}
```

Comment: This is a more formal way of approaching the problem, which is just what I needed, thanks!  Will read in depth.

I tried dividing the branching and merging into separate steps.  It makes sense to process branching first (you end up with a number of "fake" nodes which may be > Tn), then merging afterwards in the same step.

Looking forward to the pseudo code but that's really more than I dared ask for.

Comment: FYI I named Tn confusingly, it's not a multiple of T and n but just a constant, for example 5.  So Tn will be the same for timestep 19 as it is for timestep 3.

Comment: Rather than processing the chance to merge / split per node, I'd recommend deciding on split/merge events per time step, then figure out where to place them among the available nodes. That can help avoid biasing where, for instance, the nodes you process early in the iteration tend to use up the splitting headroom before the later nodes get their turn to roll the dice.

Comment: The way I was going to combat that is to process `lastLayer` in random order, I forgot to define the boolean array to go with it

Comment: Please see the "answer" I added - more of an alternative really.  I spent some time doing it all in F# and it works but there are some drawbacks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code dump after a few days of work using a functional language, F#.  I'm hesitant to mark it as an answer because that would be a snub to the time that @phflack also spent doing it in an imperative way which more people will understand.  Also his pseudo code was closer to the actual requirements I described.

This problem is unexpectedly difficult to code given even simple specifications.  I wanted to allow forks and merges in the same timestep, like this:

[image: Fork and merge]

I tackled this by first performing the fork operation, then storing the results in a sequence of "partial links".  Here there are three marked in grey (this diagram is equivalent to the above):

[image: Partial links]

The merge is then performed by considering random pairs of partial links.

Fork probability and merge probability are constants, respectively 1/4 and 1/3.  The higher merge probability acts as a soft limit on the number of nodes per timestep and acts as a replacement for the hard limit of N nodes per timestep.

Here is an example of part of a graph generated by this code:

[image: Example graph]

Using this approach, sometimes the number of paths reaches 20, and other times it stays on 1 for a long time - so it's not perfect.  This will be tweakable to an extent by changing the fork and merge probabilities.

```
open System

type Scene (text : string, links : int array) =
    member this.Text = text
    member this.Links = links

type StoryGenState = { timestepNum: uint32; currentTimestepWidth: uint32 }
type FullLink = { fromIndex: int; toIndex: int }

let forkProbability = 1.0 / 4.0
let mergeProbability = 1.0 / 3.0

let random = new Random()

let GetForkDecision() =
    if random.NextDouble() < forkProbability
    then true
    else false
let GetForkDecisions n =
    seq { for i in 1u .. n do yield GetForkDecision() } |> Seq.toArray
let GetPartialLinks (toFork : bool array) =
    seq {
            for i in 0 .. toFork.Length - 1 do
                if toFork.[i] then
                    yield i
                yield i
        }
    |> Seq.toArray
let GetMergablePairs (toFork : bool array) =
    seq {
            for i in 0 .. toFork.Length - 1 do
                if toFork.[i] then
                    yield false
                if i < toFork.Length - 1 then
                    yield true
        }
    |> Seq.toArray
let GetMergeDecision() =
    if random.NextDouble() < mergeProbability then true else false


let rec PerformMergeStep (toMerge : bool array) (isMergable : bool array) numberOfMergesToDo =
    if numberOfMergesToDo = 0 || (isMergable |> Array.contains(true) |> not)
    then
        toMerge
    else
        let mergableIndices = seq {for i in 0 .. isMergable.Length - 1 do if isMergable.[i] then yield i} |> Seq.toArray
        let indexOfIndexToMerge = random.Next(0, mergableIndices.Length)
        let indexToMerge = mergableIndices.[indexOfIndexToMerge]
        let nextToMerge = toMerge |> Array.copy
        do Array.set nextToMerge indexToMerge true
        let toFlagFirstIndex = max (indexToMerge - 1) 0
        let toFlagLastIndex = min (indexToMerge + 1) (isMergable.Length - 1)
        let toFlagCount = toFlagLastIndex - toFlagFirstIndex + 1
        let nextIsMergable = isMergable |> Array.copy
        do Array.fill nextIsMergable toFlagFirstIndex toFlagCount false
        PerformMergeStep nextToMerge nextIsMergable (numberOfMergesToDo - 1)

let GetMergeDecisions (isMergable : bool array) =
    let numberOfMergesToDo = isMergable |> Array.map(fun b -> if b then GetMergeDecision() else false) |> Array.where (fun b -> b) |> Array.length
    PerformMergeStep (Array.create isMergable.Length false) isMergable numberOfMergesToDo


let rec BuildFullLinksStep (fullLinks : FullLink list) (partialLinks : int array) (toMerge : bool array) (partialLinkIndex : int) (currentToIndex : int) =

    let nextFullLinks = fullLinks @ [{ fromIndex = partialLinks.[partialLinkIndex]; toIndex = currentToIndex }]

    if (partialLinkIndex = partialLinks.Length - 1)
    then
        nextFullLinks
    else 
        let nextToIndex = currentToIndex + (if toMerge.[partialLinkIndex] = true then 0 else 1)
        BuildFullLinksStep nextFullLinks partialLinks toMerge (partialLinkIndex + 1) nextToIndex
let BuildFullLinks (partialLinks : int array) (toMerge : bool array) =
    BuildFullLinksStep [] partialLinks toMerge 0 0
let CreateScenes (fullLinks : FullLink list) =
    seq {
            for i in 0 .. fullLinks.Length - 1 do
                Console.WriteLine("FullLink: {0},{1}", fullLinks.[i].fromIndex, fullLinks.[i].toIndex)
                if i = fullLinks.Length - 1 || fullLinks.[i + 1].fromIndex <> fullLinks.[i].fromIndex
                then
                    let tempList =
                        if i = 0 || fullLinks.[i - 1].fromIndex <> fullLinks.[i].fromIndex
                        then
                            [fullLinks.[i].toIndex]
                        else
                            [fullLinks.[i - 1].toIndex] @ [fullLinks.[i].toIndex]                            

                    let (links : int array) = tempList |> List.toArray

                    yield Scene("", links)
        }
    |> Seq.toArray
let GetNumUniqueOutputScenes (links : FullLink list) =
    links |> List.map(fun l -> l.toIndex) |> List.distinct |> List.length

let StoryGen(maxTimesteps : uint32) =
    Seq.unfold
        (
            fun (state : StoryGenState) ->
                Console.WriteLine("current step of unfold has timestep {0} and width {1}", state.timestepNum, state.currentTimestepWidth)
                Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
                if (state.timestepNum >= maxTimesteps) then
                    None
                else
                    let toFork = GetForkDecisions state.currentTimestepWidth
                    let toMerge = toFork |> GetMergablePairs |> GetMergeDecisions
                    let fullLinks : (FullLink list) = BuildFullLinks (toFork |> GetPartialLinks) toMerge
                    let scenes : (Scene array) = CreateScenes fullLinks

                    Some(scenes, { timestepNum = state.timestepNum + 1u; currentTimestepWidth = (GetNumUniqueOutputScenes fullLinks) |> uint32 })
        ) {timestepNum = 0u; currentTimestepWidth = 1u}
    |> Seq.toArray

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let story = StoryGen(240u)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```